# Pass Data to PHP using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

How can I pass the input text data in HTML to a PHP function without clicking the submit button?

I already had the idea to use Ajax to fetch the data from the database, but I only wanted to query a specific row. The idea here is whenever a name is entered on the input field `name`, it automatically queries the database. If said name exists, the other two fields, `address` and `contact`, automatically populate.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
    $server ="localhost";
    $user ="root";
    $password = "";
    $db = "customers";

    $con= new mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);

    if($con->connect_errno){
        die("cannot connect to the database".$con->connect_error);
    }

    $input = $_GET['name'];
    $sql ="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = '$input'";
    $result= $con->query($sql);
    $customer= mysqli_fetch($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($customer);
?>

<body>
<script> 
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener('change',thereExist);

function thereExist()
{
    var searchCustomer = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // here should call the php  function and pass the data from 
    input text 'name'
}

function getData()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET','fetch.php',true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status == 200){
            var customer =JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var output='';
            document.getElementById('address').value(customer.name);
            document.getElementById('contact').value(customer.contact);
        }
    }
}
</script>

<form action="" method="GET">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
    Address: <input type="text" id="address" name ="address" value="" />
    Contact: <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" value="" />
</form>    
</body>
```

Comment: You need to post some code.

Comment: post code here, not pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear like you are following the manual(s) on your attempts on the PHP or the JavaScript. You should follow the examples/guidelines set out to make the Ajax script work properly and your MySQLi implementation is also flawed in a couple key aspects. You are trying to create a class instance but you are using the procedural version of MySQLi, so I imagine there should be some sort of error generated from that. Then you are not binding parameters on the statement, thereby opening yourself up to injection. One note, I use PDO, so you will have to double check the MySQLi, I did it based on the manual guidelines:

**/fetch.php**

```
<?php
# You should think about containing your connection inside a class or function
$server ="localhost";
$user ="root";
$password = "";
$db = "customers";
# This should be the class version of this library not the function
$con = new mysqli($server,$user,$password,$db);
# This part should work now
if($con->connect_errno){
    die(json_encode(['success'=>false,'msg'=>"cannot connect to the database".$con->connect_error]));
}
# I'm gonna switch to post here...
$input = (!empty($_POST['name']))? trim($_POST['name']) : false;
# If it's empty, just stop
if(empty($input))
    die(json_encode(['success'=>false,'msg'=>'Input is empty']));
# You have to bind parameters, this is a security hole
//$sql ="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = '$input'";
# Prepare the statement with a question mark as a placeholder
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT `name`,`contact` FROM customers WHERE name = ?");
# Put the value in here, indicating it is a string (s)
$query->bind_param('s',$input);
# Execute the query
$query->execute();
# Get the results from the query
$result = $query->get_result();
# Fetch the array as associative
$customer = $result->fetch_assoc();
# Add a success row in the array so the json parse is not malformed on return
$customer = (empty($customer))? ['success'=>false] : array_merge(['success'=>true],$customer);
# Print the string
die(json_encode($customer));
```

**form page:**

```
<body>
<script> 
// Create a simple ajax function
function aPoster(dataObj)
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // Open via post
        xhr.open('POST',dataObj.sendto,true);
        // Send the header
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        // Set the success response 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                dataObj.success(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        // Send the request
        xhr.send(dataObj.values);
    };
// Shorthand to get obj by id (optional function)
function getId(elem)
{
    return document.getElementById(elem);
}
// Set the event listener
getId('name').addEventListener('change',function(){
    // Use our ajax function
    aPoster({
        // Set where to post to
        'sendto' : 'fetch.php',
        // Send the query string with value from field
        'values' : "name="+getId('name').value,
        // Set the success function for the return
        'success' : function(response){
            // I like to set a try here incase the parse fails
            try {
                // Parse
                response    =   JSON.parse(response);
                // Check if there was a successful return
                if(response.success == true) {
                    // .value is not a method, you have to assign here
                    getId('address').value = response.name;
                    getId('contact').value = response.contact;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception) {
                console.log('Return error: '+Exception.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
    Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
    Address: <input type="text" id="address" name ="address" value=""/>
    Contact: <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" value=""/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: If my, or the other answer given, solved your issue, please mark as correct so this question isn't left open.

Comment: I just made a few modifications but the code works fine. thanks :)

Comment: Great, I was wondering if it was any good, especially the MySQL stuff

Answer (score -2):

What I can understand that data should be sent when user will type into the textbox or change the select button

this is very simple within input or select tag onchange=("funtcion_name()") like below

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="input" onchange = "myFun()">
    <script>
       function myFun()
       {
          var id = $("#input").val();
          $.ajax({
              
              //write your ajax code here
          
          })
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you made serious spelling mistakes that'll lead to errors, please fix those or they might think that that is proper/correct syntax.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention jQuery, not wasting a downvote on this, but its poor.

Comment: @Rakeshkumarsharma  It’s `$.ajax` with an “a” not `$.ajex` with an “e”.

Comment: Also, you wouldn’t put Ajax code where you’ve indicated, rather you’d fill in pre-determined data object values, some of which could contain functions (code).